# Where did all the (Sublime Text) questions go?

Tags: support, questions

I'm [very](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5251/sublimetext) [active](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5093/sublimetext3) in [sublimetext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext) and all the related tags ([sublimetext2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext2), [sublimetext2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext2), [sublime-text-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime-text-plugin), etc.), so I have [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext2+or+sublimetext+or+sublimetext3+or+sublime-text-plugin+or+sublimerepl+or+sublimelinter+or+sublimecodeintel+or+sublime-jslint+or+sublime-build+or+sublimerope+or+package-control?sort=newest&pageSize=50) set up to monitor them all at once. Scrolling down the page a few minutes ago, I noticed this:

[image: Sublime questions missing]

All the questions from today were there, as well as one from yesterday, then it skipped back to one from July 24, then May 3, then December 2014, and so on. These tags (combined) typically get anywhere from a few to 10 or more questions per day, so this is definitely a bug of some sort. The missing questions still exist, because I can go to the [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426065/mattdmo?tab=answers&sort=newest) section of my profile, see them, and click on them. The only [other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+python-2.7+or+python-2.6+or+python-2.x+or+python-2.5+or+python-2.4+or+python-2.3+or+python-2.2+or+python-2.1+or+python-3.x+or+python-3.3+or+python-3.2+or+python-3.1+or+python-3.4+or+python-3.5?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=50) I have set up like this is for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and related tags, and that one seems to be working just fine, so this doesn't appear to be a universal problem.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: Another query glitch, and you got stale cached results. Click around a bit (switch from detailed to compact view, to popular to needs answers and back to new) and you get the full list again. I was able to reproduce your list then return to a full proper result again.

Comment: @Martijn it finally worked, thanks. I had to click around for a while, and ended up leaving the Votes tab active for 10 minutes or so, and when I went back to Newest it was back to normal. Never had that happen before. Strange...

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/?